# Alias: binds with multiple arguments

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to create an alias, that runs a bind with 2 arguments (forward and getout)

```
alias +ERw "+forward;getout" // This creates a variable with 2 arguments if you press the button
alias -ERw "-forward;getout" // This creates a variable with 2 arguments if you release the button
alias ERw "bind w +ERw"      // This creates a variable to bind it to the button "w"
```

If I call ERw, it doesn't do anything, but if I enter "bind w +ERw" in the console, it does actually work.

What't the problem, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, had to make a lot of aliases.

```
alias ERw1 "+forward"
alias ERw2 "-forward"
alias +ERw3 "ERw1;getout"
alias -ERw3 "ERw2;getout"
alias ERw4 "bind w +ERw3"
alias ERw5 "bind w +forward"
```